# StackOverflow Exception during loading list of users' profiles using TweetSharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I'am using latest version of TweetSharp for loading users' profiles.
Firstly, I load all followers of user using `ListFollowerIdsFor` method.
After that, I divide all ids into list with up to 100  ids.

```
 
var ids = newUsersIds.Skip(i * 100).Take(100).Distinct().ToList();
var users = service.ListUserProfilesFor(new ListUserProfilesForOptions { UserId = ids });
```

And sometimes I get `StackoverflowException` on this line.
Last two lines in call stack:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x17a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
```

Recursion in

```
    TweetSharp.dll!TweetSharp.JsonSerializer.DeserializeContent(string content, System.Type type) Line 168 + 0x1b bytes C#
    TweetSharp.dll!TweetSharp.JsonSerializer.DeserializeSingle(string content, System.Type type) Line 223 + 0x11 bytes  C#
    TweetSharp.dll!TweetSharp.JsonSerializer.DeserializeJson(string content, System.Type type) Line 41 + 0xe bytes  C#
```

How can I prevent it?

Comment: i is just iterator for Skiping

Comment: look at the call stack when exception is thrown. If you can't make sense of it - post in the question.

Comment: Web.Exception in call stack is last

Comment: The thread '<No Name>' (0x17a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: fyi, that is a really suboptimal way of chunking into lots of 100 :) try this: public static List<List<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
        {
            return source
                .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToList();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in handling HTTP 500 error "Twitter over capacity". Tweetsharp tries to serialize html page in this situation.

Comment: I think you will find there is some indirect recursion happening in the deserializer. not sure if it's your issue, but it's definitely mine.